# Does every episode of Would I Lie to You? follow the same pattern?

Tags: production, would-i-lie-to-you

I recently discovered *Would I Lie to You* and it's very entertaining.

However, after watching about 20 different situations, I feel like there's a pattern. Lee and David are always the ones who are lying, and the other guests are always telling the truth.

This makes sense from the producers point of view, since they don't know how good the guests would be at lying.

My question is, is this a real pattern? Or something I see just because I have a small sample size?

Comment: "Lee and David are always the ones who are lying" This is not true.

Comment: @Vishwa, what you've change the question title to no longer has any bearing on the actual question.

Comment: @BCdotWEB Yes I would be extremely surprised if it was true 100% of the time, but is it true most of the time?

Comment: @Ovi Some true Lee & David stories (spoilers, obviously): https://www.radiotimes.com/news/2016-09-09/the-10-most-surprising-truths-on-would-i-lie-to-you/ Also, don't forget you see an edit of a much longer taping where they only keep the funny stories etc. or whatever fits in the slightly-less-than-thirty-minutes format.

Comment: It probably makes sense for Lee and David to be lying more often than they're telling the truth. They're the regular team captains on the show, rather than occasional guests, so it would be harder for them to always have a true story that fits the show's requirements.

Answer (score 4):

No it's not a real pattern.

Especially if you are watching later seasons, David and Lee are likely to be lying as they have mostly "run out" of interesting truths. However, this is still not a hard rule, and occasionally some new unlikely development has occurred.

On the other side, if you are watching selected clips of guests e.g. on YouTube then they're likely to be true. It's more interesting to learn something surprising about a celebrity than just listen to them make stuff up.

On many occasions the guests have been lying (indeed the format of "This is my..." requires at least one of them to lie), and both David and Lee have told the truth. This [top-10 truths](https://www.radiotimes.com/news/2016-09-09/the-10-most-surprising-truths-on-would-i-lie-to-you/) consists entirely of Rob, David and Lee.